# Trouble Extracting part of file path inside of for /r

Tags: string, loops, batch-file, for-loop

I'm having trouble setting up a way to transcode a set of files in sub folders into a target directory while maintaining the same sub directories.

Example:

> C:\massiveVideoFiles\Back to the future\BTF.mp4
>   ...\Lord of the Rings\LOTR.mp4

end up

> C:\smallVideoFiles\Back to the future\BTF.mkv
>   ...\Lord of the Rings\LOTR.mkv

While transcoding it needs to be in a temp folder then moved to the correct output directory.

```
setlocal
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /p src="Source Directory"
set /p trg="Target Directory"
call strLen.cmd %src% len
echo %len%
pause

for /R "%src%" %%f in (*.mp4 *.mkv) do (
    REM Trying to remove the source file path and only keep the remaining folder tree
    set subpath=%%f:~%len%
    cls
    echo %subpath%
    pause

    ffmpeg.exe -y -analyzeduration 99999999999 -probesize 99999999999 -i "%%f" -preset medium -rc vbr_hq -cq 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy -c:s copy -c:v hevc_nvenc "%trg%\temp\%subpath%.mkv"
    pause
    cls

    robocopy /s /mov "%trg%\temp" "%trg%"
    pause
    cls

    rd /q /s "%trg%\temp"
    pause
    echo off
    cls
)

pause
```

I was just using `src` and `trg` with `%~pfn.mkv` but the result was

> C:\smallVideoFiles\massiveVideoFiles\Back to the future\BTF.mkv

I am looking for

> C:\smallVideoFiles\Back to the Future\BTF.mkv

Comment: Just as a side note: you cannot do sub-string expansion like `set subpath=%%f:~%len%` on `for` meta-variables, it works only for normal environment variables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to let `for /R` expand its loop variable as a path relative to its root.

However, for tasks like this I tend to use the [`xcopy` command](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)) together wit its `/L` option (list but do not actually copy anything), because this returns relative paths, which can then be appended to the destination:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Enter data here:
set /P _SOURCE="Source Directory: "
set /P _TARGET="Target Directory: "

rem // Change to source directory:
pushd "%_SOURCE%" && (
    rem // Change to target directory just to check for existence:
    pushd "%_TARGET%" && (
        rem // Return from target directory to source directory:
        popd
        rem /* Loop over the output of `xcopy /L`; since we are in the source directory, `xcopy`
        rem    returns relative paths of all items prefixed with the source drive letter plus a
        rem    `:`, which we use as the delimiter for the `for /F` loop: */
        for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%E in ('
            rem/ Place multiple `xcopy` commands here, one per the source mask: ^& ^
                xcopy /L /S "*.mp4" "%_TARGET%" ^& ^
                xcopy /L /S "*.mkv" "%_TARGET%" ^& ^
                rem/
        ') do (
            rem // Skip the (empty) summary lines returned by `xcopy`:
            if not "%%F"=="" (
                rem // Do something with the relative path like appending it to the destination:
                set "SFILE= %%~fF"
                set "TFILE=%_TARGET%\%%F"
                rem // Use built full destination path, applying delayed expansion:
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                echo(!SFILE! -^> !TFILE!
                endlocal
            )
        )
    )
    rem // Return to original working directory:
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: I think this is more what I'm looking for. As a noob at this I'm going to have to look up a few of these commands and symbols to fully grasp. The comments really helped! One thing I didn't make clear is the video files can be dumped in the root of the sub-directory or nested in folders like 
%_SOURCE%\BTTF.mp4 
and 
%_SOURCE%/StarTrek/Season01/episode01.mp4.

If I understand correctly it should handle the latter just fine, but would skip the first example because there is no sub-folder?

Comment: I'm having trouble running multiple commands inside the if not "%%F"=="" block, but I'm going to start a new post for better clarity.

Comment: There should be no difference if there's one or more commands. Anyway, if you set and read the same variable inside of that `if` block, ensure to have [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled; I'm going to extend my answer concerning this, because I guess that's what's causing trouble, since you've got that wrong in your question also...

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is trying to remove all directories in the tree from Drive Letter, First Directory TO Last Folder, File; - Example: `C:\smallVideoFiles\` & `\Back to the Future\BTF.mkv` Then this is the solution you might be looking for.

To find the Drive Letter & First Dir, we can use a simple loop with `tokens=1,2,3* delims=\`. This will have `%%A` & `%%B` be the only important data we need.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3* delims=\" %%A in ('echo %%~dpi') do (
    Set "Drive=%%A\%%B"
)
```

For getting the last folder it's a little more complicated but in common sence we will use a loop to gather just the last folder using `%%~nxA`.

```
Set "String=%%~dpi"
    Set "String=!String:~0,-1%!"
    Set "FileName=%%~nxi"

    for %%A in (!String!) do (
    set "LastFolder=%%~nxA"
)
```

By combining these strings together we get your new directory result. 
**Batchfile.bat:**

```
@ECHO OFF
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /p src="Source Directory"
set /p trg="Target Directory"
call strLen.cmd %src% len

for /R "%src%" %%i in (*.mp4 *.mkv) do (

    Echo Original: %%i

    Rem | Get Drive Letter & First Dir
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3* delims=\" %%A in ('echo %%~dpi') do (
        Set "Drive=%%A\%%B"
    )

    Rem | Get File.Extension & One Dir Back
    Set "String=%%~dpi"
    Set "String=!String:~0,-1%!"
    Set "FileName=%%~nxi"

    for %%A in (!String!) do (
        set "LastFolder=%%~nxA"
    )

    Echo New: !Drive!\!LastFolder!\!FileName!

    Rem | Continue Code
    ffmpeg.exe -y -analyzeduration 99999999999 -probesize 99999999999 -i "%%f" -preset medium -rc vbr_hq -cq 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy -c:s copy -c:v hevc_nvenc "%trg%\temp\%subpath%.mkv"
    pause
    cls

    robocopy /s /mov "%trg%\temp" "%trg%"
    pause
    cls

    rd /q /s "%trg%\temp"
    pause
    cls

)

pause
```